# NotImplementedException when overriding default phone resources

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm am adding the following code to the constructor of App.xaml.cs in my WP7 application.

```
Resources["PhoneBackgroundBrush"] = new ImageBrush
{
    ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/images/bg.png", UriKind.Relative))
};
```

after running it I get NotImplementedException once the applicaion is opened.

Any idea of how can we do this?

What I'm trying to achieve is a single theme application like Facebook that always have white theme regardless of phone's theme.

As a note, getter on the resources always work, so it's not that accessing phone resources is totally blocked from code. (I'm using this to determine current theme and accent of phone).

```
var a = Resources["PhoneBackgroundBrush"]; // this works fine
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple examples it isn't complicated when you know how, however you shouldn't rename PhoneBackgroundBrush, but create a new key for your resources.

You need to create the resources in App.xaml (or you can pull in MergedDictionaries other places too, but that's more advanced). `Test.jpg` needs to be a resource file in your project.

In App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ImageBrush x:Key="MyImageBrush" ImageSource="Test.jpg"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

In a page for example:

```
Background="{StaticResource MyImageBrush}"
```

If you're starting to re-template a control (say a Button), that when you need to crack open Blend and modify the default styles of controls. It's pretty well documented, and builds on these same principles...

Comment: The reason I'm doing it programaticaly is to have it dynamically set to different things (based on some criterias).

Comment: You could always retrieve the object from the resource dictionary in your App.xaml.cs and modify it when your app starts up. I'd watch out if modifying it elsewhere though.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the reason you're getting a NotImplementedException is because the **setter** for the Application.Resources is implemented like this:

```
set 
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

The reason Facebook is all white, is because they defined their own colour resources, and used them everywhere. I've also made a always-white themed app. It just requires a little extra effort.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe they compile their app in a different way to shorten the pain :) but explicitly assigning custom resource to all controls is not doable for me

Comment: Most controls inherit the Foreground and Background from other controls. It's not at all difficult. You already spend more time asking on SO, than it would take to do it with a good tool like Expression Blend.

Comment: It's easier in WP7 Mango as it uses SL4 which allows you to set a default template for each control type. That means you don't have to remember to apply your template to every single control of that type in your project...